# Updating a Document on Firestore with a field value with space in it, does not update it in DB

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Probably poorly worded.

I have a Firestore Collection called users, and I want to update the Document for a particular id with a data json using Python, and Firebase admin SDK in Python. Here is the code

```
uname = l[1]
usermail = l[4]

tags = ["xxxyyy"]

datajson = {"emailVerified": "False",
    "status":"active",
    "name": uname,
    "uid":"",
    "tag":tags,
    "email": usermail,
    }
print(datajson)

try:
    datajson["uid"] = userid  (From some other code)
    db.collection('users').document(data["Doc ID"]).set(datajson)
```

Whenever I run this with name say "Wolfgang Alpha", the db is updated with "name: name" as the property and not "name: Wolfgang Alpha". The reason I think it is with space is because I tried with one word name and it worked.

I am using this on Python3.7. Please help. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Firestore lets you write a variety of data types inside a document, including strings, booleans, numbers, dates, null, and nested arrays and objects. As you can see on the [doc examples](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#data_types), string value is accepted and the spacing is preserved.

I suggest that you check the value of `uname` first if it's correct and consider updating your Firebase Admin SDK to latest version, though the Admin SDK supports Python 3.6+ so it's unlikely that this is an SDK issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I figured it out. It was an old cloud function which was messing things up. It was intermittent because sometimes my code would execute first and sometimes the cloud function would. Really stupid error on my part.